# Calling variables from objects from another object.

Tags: java, oop

When I'm writing a little bit more complex program, I always get confused on how to build my program. I would like to give an example, without needing the code to be fixed. But to understand what is the best or most correct way to do this.

Example program:

Now I want to different things with my program (without using Java date class or Yoda time).

1. I want to check if a year is a leap year
2. I want to check on which day a given date is;
3. I want to check in which years this day was the same.
4. Compare two dates, and count months, days etc.

For implementing this kind of function, there are certain things to be aware of:

1. Is a year a leap year
2. On which day was january the 1st.
3. Does the year has 52 or 53 weeks?

When an date is created, a new Data object is created with day, month and year object. With the dates, for example 05-11-2002. Will create a new Date object, with new Year object, new Month object and new Day object (holding 2012, 11, 5).

I've created a new Date class that consists of:

```
public class Date {
    Year year;
    Month month;
    Day day;
```

For my year class I just take the year in an int, and check if the year is a leap year:

```
public class Year {
    int year; 
    boolean leapyear;
```

So far so good, no really big problems.

In my month class, I only take the int month;

```
 public class Month {
    int month;
```

However, in my day classes I need more options. In my Day class I need to day more things.

1. I need to figure out the total days of a given a month, day and leapyear (YES/NO).
2. Check january the first for a given year
3. Check the day for a given day and year.

So I need the data from other objects, from my Year and Month objects. Here is my example of the first point (figure out which number a certain day has in a year).

```
    public class Day {

        int day; 
        int dayTotal;  
        int januaray1st; 


    public void daytotal(int m, int d, boolean leapyear) {


        int day = 0; 

        if (m == 0) {
            days = 0; 
        }
        if (m == 1) {
            days = 31; 
        }
        if (m == 2) {
            days = 59; 
        }
        if (m == 3) {
            days = 90; 
        }
        if (m == 4) {
            days = 120; 
        }
        if (m == 5) {
            days = 151; 
        }
        if (m == 6) {
            days = 181; 
        }
        if (m == 7) {
            days = 212; 
        }
        if (m == 8) {
            days = 243; 
        }
        if (m == 9) {
            days = 273; 
        }
        if (m == 10) {
            days = 304; 
        }
        if (m == 11) {
            days = 334; 
        }




        if (leapyear = true && m > 1) {
        days += 1; 
        } else {
        days = d + days; 
        }
        this.dayTotal = days; 
  }
```

What is the best way to do this?

I this exmample I want to use the leapYear method with the variables from my Day and Year objects. In this situation I usually encounter problems. Usually I figure it with trial and error, but i would like to know what is the best way to handle this?

Question
1. What is the nicest way to your methods in a situation like this? Should I make a testDate.java, or any other way?

Comment: `leapyear = true` should be `leapyear == true`

Comment: Joda-Time, please.  Otherwise you'd be saying "Is 16 date October today's."

Comment: Try replacing `if(m == 0) ... if(m == 1) ... etc` with `switch(m) { case 0: ... case 1: ...`  As for the rest of your question, I suggest parsing this down and deal with little bits at a time being very specific.  You're asking a LOT here and I don't know where to begin.  Edit your question down to a much smaller scope and be very specific.

Comment: @peeskillet The question is tagged `oop`, and it looks like it's either homework-related or the questioner is just trying to teach himself.  If he's wanting to improve his understanding of `oop`, it's probably important to work on learning how `classes` interact with each other.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis With properly named boolean variables you shouldn't have to use equality/inequality tests.  It's cleaner as `if (leapyear && m > 1)`.

Comment: It is not clear what you intend with points 2 and 3. "Check january the first for a given year" - what should a method which did that return? Same for "Check the day for a given day and year" - what does "check the day" mean?